# Exception when trying to navigate from one form to another

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I am new to c#. And I was trying to navigate from one form to another using this code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=xxxx-PC;database=node;uid=sa;pwd=xxxx;");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update nodes set filein='" + textBox1.Text + "' where id='" + textBox2.Text + "' ", con);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        this.Hide();

        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.show();
    }
```

but it hides one form and throws an exception:

> method or operation is not implemented

Comment: thx frnd ..can anyone help on this code

Comment: One of the worst questions ever. Most code irrelevant, tags are wrong (nothing related to sql server matters here) and - the technology (WInforms or WPF) is not given. Man, you really hit it low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to find what exactly your error is:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=xxxx-PC;database=node;uid=sa;pwd=xxxx;");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update nodes set filein='" + textBox1.Text + "' where id='" + textBox2.Text + "' ", con);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        this.Hide();
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        //error here
        //form2.show();
        //replace this with
        form2.Show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: it throws the same error as ' method or operation is not implemented '